# как создать карту для игры, scroll во все стороны, kotlin android?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, карты

создаю настольную игру и хочу создать карту больше экрана.. как её сделать, что использовать? чтобы можно было по ней перемещаться как в google картах по горизонтали, вертикали, диагонали и взаимодействовать с объектами на карте, изменять их..  хочу по типу плоского шара, т.е. если долго скролить вправо, то приходим снова на то же место где и были и т.д.

Comment: Я последние лет 8 видел как люди тут спрашивали подобное. За эти 8 лет пришёл к выводу, что единственный нормальный способ - на канвасе вручную рисовать каждый пиксель, отслеживая тачи по экрану, вычисляя сколько было проскролено, какие теперь условные координаты надо на экране отобразить и вручную отрисовать то, что по этим координатам должно у вас находится. Т.е. простого решения не будет, надо что-то типа своего 2D движка сооружать. Возможно вам стоит посмотреть в сторону какого-то уже готового, где большую часть нужного вам уже кто-то написал.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, попробую пока что сам.. а если не получится, то какой движок порекомендовать можете для подобных затей?

Comment: В движках не разбираюсь, порекомендовать ничего не могу. Разве что не советую libGdx. т.к. мало инфы в интернете по нему

Answer (score 0):

Единственный готовый (и не устаревший) способ сделать это, который я сумел найти в интернете - `LibGDX`. Идею делать вручную движок под это - практически сразу будет тобой отброшена, ибо лично я пол года пытался это сделать и единственное чего добился - отображение картинки с возможностью масштабирования (мега кривого). Как сказал автор выше - нужно использовать движок, но я не рекомендую, ибо если проект не слишком крупный (даже на уровне того же майна или террарии), то движок будет весить половину файла и жрать две трети всех ресурсов.

Answer (score -1):

Android Studio создана для создания приложений и в связи с этим не имеет никаких удобных возможностей для создания игр.

Для лёгкого и удобного процесса осуществления вашей цели нужно использовать среду разработки игр, например, Unity (используется язык C#).